# Ajuda pra subtrair 2 resultados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ola alguém da uma forcinha aqui coom esse codigo , gostaria de pegar o valor da entrada menos a saida subtrair no caso, segue meu codigo abaixo !

```
<script src="jquery_somar.js"></script>

<!--  1 Soma das Entradas -->  

Soma das Entradas 

<div class="Entradas">100,00</div>
<div class="Entradas">100,00</div>
<br>
<div id="resultado_entradas"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

var total = $('.Entradas').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
    var numero = el.innerHTML.split('.').join('').split(',').join('.');
    return tot + Number(numero);
}, 0);
$('#resultado_entradas').html(total.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2}));
    </script>


<!--  2 Soma das Saidas -->   


<div class="Saidas">10,00</div>
<div class="Saidas">10,00</div>
<div id="resultado_saidas"></div>   




    <script type="text/javascript">

var total = $('.Saidas').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
    var numero = el.innerHTML.split('.').join('').split(',').join('.');
    return tot + Number(numero);
}, 0);
$('#resultado_saidas').html(total.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2}));
    </script>
```

Total: ID resultado_entradas - ID resultado_saidas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso podes usar a classe para saber qual é e trocar de positivo para negativo num somatório.

Algo assim:

```
var total = $('.Saidas, .Entradas').get().reduce(function(tot, el) {
    var numero = Number(el.innerHTML.split('.').join('').split(',').join('.'));
    return tot + (el.classList.contains('Entradas') ? numero : -numero);
}, 0);
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kycym5wz/